# Running Electron App dependancies

Tags: node.js, arm, debian, electron

I built an app using `electron` and `electron-packager`.

The app will run exclusively on some low-power industrial tablets running Linux (debian) on ARM7l processors.

I'm actually building the application on the tablet itself, and it's working great - by running the app in the terminal with `./AppName`.

Here's the problem - I'm trying to run the same app in another tablet (same kind of tablet - with ARM7l and same distro). But when I try the same `./Appname` line in the terminal, I get `Command not found` errors.

Is there an OS dependency I'm missing? The [Electron Docs](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/supported-platforms/) under Linux state:

> Whether the prebuilt binary can run on a distribution depends on whether the distribution includes the libraries that Electron is linked to on the building platform, so only Ubuntu 12.04 is guaranteed to work...

But for the life of me, I can't seem to find any reference to the **libraries that Electron is linked to** on the web.

Any wise words?

Comment: "But when I try the same ./aAppname line in the terminal" - is that simply a typo (./aAppname)?

Comment: @PaulStoner typo fixed - thanks